# Classifying text documents using linear/incremental topics

Tags: classification, scikit-learn

I'm attempting to classify text documents using a few different dimensions. I'm trying to create arbitrary topics to classify such as size and relevance, which are linear or gradual in nature. For example:

size: tiny, small, medium, large, huge. 
relevance: bad, ok, good, excellent, awesome

I am training the classifier by hand. For example, this document represents a 'small' thing, this other document is discussing a 'large' thing. When I try multi-label or multi-class SVM for this it does not work well and it also logically doesn't make sense.

Which model should I use that would help me predict this linear type of data? I use scikit-learn presently with a tfidf vector of the words.

Comment: maybe I just need to add another vector in addition to the words...? but that seems odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want these output dimensions to be continuous, simply convert your size and relevance metrics to real-valued targets.  Then you can perform [regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) instead of classification, using any of a variety of models.  You could even attempt to train a multi target neural net to predict all of these outputs at once.

Additionally, you might consider first using  a [topic model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model) such as [LDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) as your feature space.

Based on the values, it sounds like the "relevance" might be a variable best captured by techniques from [sentiment analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis).

Comment: can you give examples of how one would perform regression on a bag of words?

Comment: If you used LDA for example, each document would be represented by a topic vector.  You could then transform your labels ("big", "small", etc) into real-values (big=100,small=10,tiny=1) and perform any kind of regression, even simple linear regression, to predict the real-valued targets.

There are a number of places you could get implementations of LDA.  What language are you using?

Comment: We're using python and scikit-learn. I've used LDA and LSA for topic modelling, but I'm not sure how that fits onto my labels. And what about just using a tfidf vector of the document words?

Comment: Sure, tf-idf vectors might be sufficient.  If you need your output labels to be ordered, you need to either assign real values to the targets (as I said above). In order to go from tf-idf vectors or topic vectors to your labels, you would either use any kind of regression (if you map labels to numbers) or a classifier (which it sounds like you've already tried).